# Como criar uma fragment ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, view

Eu tenho o seguinte `Fragment`:

```
public class ListaBimestresFragment extends Fragment {

    public ListaBimestresFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_bimestres, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

coloquei ele dentro do `OnClickListener`, assim:

```
public class FormularioDisciplina extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario_disciplina);

        Button adicionarBimeste = findViewById(R.id.formulario_adicionar_bim);
        adicionarBimeste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.formulario_main, new ListaBimestresFragment());
                tx.commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Acontece que ao rodar e clicar no botão, ele dá um aviso:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!
  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Como posso resolver isso?

XML main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Preencha os campos abaixo:"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/formulario_materia"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp"
        android:hint="Matéria"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/formulario_professor"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp"
        android:hint="Professor"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/formulario_obs"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp"
        android:hint="Observações"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Adicione seus bimestres"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/formulario_adicionar_bim"/>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/insert_point"/>
```

XML Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/adicionar_Layout"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/formulario_nota1"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Primeira nota"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/formulario_nota2"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Segunda nota"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Essa mensagem pode aparecer quando você tem processos longos e por isso as frames são ignoradas ou por causa do emulador, 36 frames é um número pequeno, se for maior que 100, precisaria realizar algo pra evitar isso. Dá uma lida aqui: [Processos e encadeamentos](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) 

Em relação a criar um fragment ao clicar no botão, você precisa especificar alguma mensagem de erro que está acontecendo. Forneça também o xml da sua main e do seu fragment.

Comment: @MurilloComino adicionei o XML deles na pergunta. Em relação a mensagem de erro, não aparece nada quando clico, apenas a mensagem que coloquei na pergunta ao abrir a intent. Desde já obrigado por responder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu XML Main, Coloca o seu `FrameLayout` embaixo do `Button` e dentro do `LinearLayout`.

E ao invés de:

```
tx.replace(R.id.formulario_main, new ListaBimestresFragment());
```

Coloque:

```
tx.replace(R.id.insert_point, new ListaBimestresFragment());
```

Isso já adiciona o seu `Fragment`, mas o seu código está criando apenas um campo, e toda vez que aperta o botão "+" ele substitui o `Fragment` anterior por um novo, ao invés de criar um novo campo. Caso queira adicionar novos campos eu aconselho dar uma lida nisso:

[Dynamically Add and Remove Views in Android](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android)